# Java calculating in a class funciton

Tags: java

I have the problem, that a value in a void function won't calculate :(
The task is, to calculate the invoice amount with the inserted quantity and the inserted price. Inserting and displaying the price and quantity is no problem, the problem is calculating the invoice amount.

Here is the test class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class invoicetest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        invoice newinvoice = new invoice();

        System.out.println("Please input the quantity:");
        newinvoice.setQuantity (input.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Please input the price:");
        newinvoice.setPrice (input.nextDouble());
        newinvoice.displayMessage();    
    }

}
```

And here is the invoice class:

```
public class invoice {
    private int quantity;
    private double price, amount;
    public double invoiceamount;

    public int getQuantity () {
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice () {
        return price;
    }

    public void setQuantity (int i) {
        quantity = i;
    }

    public void setPrice (double i) {
        price = i;
    }

    public double getInvoiceAmount () {

        amount = quantity*price;

        return amount;
    }

    public void setInvoiceAmount (double i) {
        invoiceamount = i;
    }

    public void displayMessage() {
        System.out.println(quantity);
        System.out.println(price);
        System.out.println(invoiceamount);
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the variable amount is constant 0. I am new to java and I don't get the problem. 
I think the quantity and the price aren't available for the void InvoiceAmount right? How do I get them, so the other functions can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set invoiceAmount anywhere.

```
public double getInvoiceAmount () {

    amount = quantity*price;

    return amount;
}
```

So just call `setInvoiceAmount` with the result you got from `getInvoiceAmount()`.

```
public void setInvoiceAmount (double i) {
    invoiceamount = i;
}
```

So in your `invoiceTest` class, add this before trying to print the values:

```
double amount = newInvoice.getInvoiceAmount();
newInvoice.setInvoiceAmount(amount);
```

Also, please respect the java naming convention, use camelCase. It is hard for others to read your code.

An useful technique to debug problems like this is to add print statements to track the variable. Start from the first place where the variable is set, and each time the variable is changed add a print statement to see how it is changing. Eventually you'll find out where it goes wrong.

Comment: How do I do this? Just change the order and calculate in the set function?

Comment: You already have all the functions you need. Just call them :)

Comment: It worked :) Thank you very much. What do you mean with camelCase? Writing the class name with an uppercase?

Comment: Should this answer your question, it is customary to mark the answer as accepted(there is a checkmark at the top left corner of the answer).

Comment: With the naming convention, I mean class names, variable names, method names, all kinds of names really. Check this page for example: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-135089.html